# Не работает NotBlank(), чтобы предотвратить отправки пустого текстового сообщение в Symphony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, валидация

у меня не работает NotBlank() в типе TextareaType,
мне нужно, чтобы пользователь не мог отправлять пустое текстовое сообщение.

Я написал код но оно не работает. Как быть подскажите пожалуйста.

Вот часть кода:

```
->add('text',TextareaType::class,[
                "required" => true,
                "label" => false,
                "constraints" => [
                    new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Please type something')),
                    new Length(['min' => 1]),
                ],
                "attr" => array(
                    'class' => 'text-editor form-control'
                )
            ])
```

P.S. Код сам работает и сообщение отправляется, но не работает именно notBlank().

Comment: Ну так выведите данные формы, может там действительно что-то есть или что-то не то приходит.

Comment: а попробуйте сделать валидацию через аннотации, может будет иной результат

Answer (score 0):

Я предполагаю вот что. В документации интересная сноска

> "When a form is only partially submitted (for example, in an HTTP
>   PATCH request), only the constraints from the submitted form fields
>   will be evaluated."

Т.е. получается если у вас форма не привязана к модели, а формирует массив, например, то в случае если у вас в  запросе не будет поля text (из за того что там пусто, в реквест попросту не попадает поле), то и не вызывается валидация, т.к. данное поле не заполняется. Что конечно порождает интересную ситуацию - валидацию вы ставите на проверку не пустого поля, а она не выполняется, потому что у вас пустое поле!

И что же делать ?

1. Явный (и с моей точки зрения более верный) вариант использовать все таки класс модели, где ограничения нужно описать в аннотации.
2. Не явный - это с фронта слать пустое поле в форме, которое не шлется по-умолчанию. Т.е. при отправке дополнительно проверять данное свойство и если пустое - слать его пустым все равно. Но это так себе вариант, самый фиговый.
3. В контроллере брать из реквеста форму, смотреть данное поле там и если его нет - добавлять его пустым. (ну тоже не очень, правда ? Представьте если у вас появилось несколько таких случаев...)

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html#adding-validation